# .htaccess и изменения на поиске Яндекса

Tags: .htaccess

Есть сайт, который участвует в рекламе Директ и Адвордс
на нём три копии папок для html-страниц по сути три одинаковых независимых сайта.

- html - основная папка
- ghtml - те же страницы но для Адвордс и для переходов c поиска Гугла
- yhtml - те же страницы но для Директ и для переходов c поиска Яндекса

Для страниц из папки html - index.html находится в корне

Для `ghtml` и `yhtml` - файлы `index.html` находятся в папках `ghtml` и `yhtml` соответственно.

Таким образом, разделяются переходы с разных источников.

Подключили с помощью `index.php` свою систему сбора информации о посетителях.

В корне находится `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html?$ /index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} google [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ghtml/index.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpe?g|png|css|js)$
RewriteRule ^index.html$ /ghtml/index.html [L,R=302]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} yandex [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/yhtml/index.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpe?g|png|css|js)$
RewriteRule ^index.html$ /yhtml/index.html [L,R=302]
```

Всё работало, пока что-то не изменили на поиске Яндекса и теперь переходы с поиска Яндекса не фиксируются,
с помощью `index.php`.

Что не так?

Comment: Вам надо выяснить что яндекс поменял у себя, раз у вас все работало до этого.

Comment: Выяснить у них быстро не получается. Может кто уже сталкивался с этим же?